# Reload weights into fc layer after converting to csr_matrix

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I am trying to store weights in a the fc layers in a compressed sparse row format. When I retrieve the weights and convert them to CSR matrix format, its size in memory reduces drastically but when I load it back into caffe my model size remains the same. Basically this is what I'm doing:

```py
temp2 = net.params['ip1'][0].data.shape
sparse_csr1 = sparse.scr_matrix(temp2, shape)
net.params['ip1'][0].data[...] = sparse_csr1
net.save('compressed.caffemodel')
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: related caffe github [issue](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/5847).

Answer (score 0):

Caffe does not support sparse matices, therefore you cannot benefit from sparse compression of weights.

Comment: I have been trying to implement the steps in this paper [Deep Compression](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.00149) and the authors stated that they stored their weights in csr format after pruning. I was wondering how that was done since they used caffe

Comment: they might override the save and load methods of caffe.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like these repos does exactly this for both inner-product and conv layers:

- https://github.com/IntelLabs/SkimCaffe
- https://github.com/valeriifilevsc/caffe